Generator Inlet Box Setup
I am thinking of connecting a 30 amp generator inlet box to my house. I have a 200 amp electrical panel outside by meter that only has main breaker and central heating and cooling unit connected. I also have a 200 amp panel inside with all other connections. I want know if connecting to outside panel is ok and best location or if the inlet box should be wired to inside panel box. I will also be installing a generator interlock kit.
The pictures below of the inside and outside panels.  First one is inside and other two are of the outside.




Can you post photos of the outside panel please, including any labeling on the inside of the door, or at the very least the make/model of the outside panel?

Welcome to DIY.SE! If the panel at the meter and the panel in the house both have compatible generator interlocks available, then this comes down to where you want to put the generator during a power outage, which seems opinion-based and off-topic for DIY.SE. If one panel has a
compatible interlock and the other doesn't, then the panel with the interlock gets the generator. If your meter pole is more out in the open than the place on the house where the inside panel is closest, then theft issues may be more a problem putting the generator at the power pole.

@ThreePhaseEel images are attached.  Triplefault, I checked the outside panel and the interlock will fit both inside and outside panel.

Either location will work. In either location you will need an appropriate interlock. Something like this GE-compatible interlock:

Both your inside and outside panels have the same basic layout - a 4-space main breaker, a large gap and branch breakers below. But there are variants and you need to make sure the interlock is a proper match for the panel or it just won't install or work correctly.
Advantages:

Inside

Easier access (but you will have to go outside to turn on the generator anyway)


Outside

Inlet can be installed near the panel without having to run wires through the wall
HVAC can be run on the generator, as long as you have enough power



Since an interlock is purely passive and mechanical, there is no "will last longer inside" concern as there is with a lot of other equipment.
You will most likely need to move breakers (definitely with the example I found) to make the interlock work in either panel because the top-right is in use and that is where your inlet breaker needs to go. In the outside panel you have plenty of room. In the inside in panel you have four spare spaces currently and will finish with just two spare spaces. Which means that if you put this inside then the last two spaces should be reserved for a future subpanel feed.

Thank you very much for the detailed response. I will likely go with the outside connection as the setup is a little easier than the inside panel connection. The interlock is different than the one I have so I may get the one you suggested as well. I will let you know how it goes.
